# Spivak Calculus Limit Intuition Clarification

Tags: calculus, limits

This is from page 94 of Spivak's "Calculus" 4th edition. He builds up the definition of a limit from examples, but I am confused about this paragraph:

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ (for $x \neq 0$)

> To show in general that $f$ approaches $1/a$ near $a$ for any $a$ we proceed in basically the same way, except that, again, we have to be a little more careful in formulating our initial stipulation. It's not good enough simply to require that $|x-a|$ should be less than 1, or any other particular number, **because if $a$ is close to 0 this would allow values of $x$ that are negative** (not to mention the embarrassing possibility that $x=0$, so that $f(x)$ isn't even defined!).

Why would negative values of $x$ be bad in this example? Couldn't the value of $a$ be negative, since $f(x)$ is defined for $x < 0$?

Comment: If $a$ is a positive number close to $0$, there could be a negative number $x$ close to $a$ but with $\dfrac 1x$ far from $\dfrac1a$

Comment: Neither of the answers so far addresses the point made in the last sentence of the question. (Nor can I address it, because I've been unable to find the relevant passage in the third edition of Spivak's book.)

Comment: When you wrote "Couldn't the value of $a$ be negative", did you mean "Couldn't the value of $x$ be negative"?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, that was actually supposed to be $x$. The answers below both provided some great insight, but I still do not understand why Spivak pointed out that negative values are bad, specifically. If $a$ is negative, shouldn't allowing a negative $x$ be okay?

Comment: @david_sap's answer explains what could go wrong when $a$ is close to zero, but this could happen for both positive and negative values. Spivak does not specify that $a$ is positive, just that it is "close to zero".

Comment: @CalumGilhooley It's in the middle of page 94.

Comment: @lyeeke I believe it's an error and he simply meant "values of $x$ that are of the opposite sign". See this similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3300921/show-that-for-any-a-ne-0-fx-1-x-approaches-1-a-as-x-approaches-a

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that $f(x)$ is defined for $x<0$ (though it is not defined for $x=0$), but it could be a problem that $x<0$ is close to $a>0$ but $\dfrac1x$ is not close to $\dfrac1a$, when studying $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

To understand why negative x values would be bad you should consider the graph of 1/x [image: f(x) = 1/x].

In particular you should focus on the two different behaviors of the function when it approaches 0 from the left (from the negative side) or from the right (from the positive side).

If you want to show that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 1/a$ you should be careful when choosing your interval on the x axis when $|a|$ is small: if your $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ open interval centered at $a$ (for $\delta > 0$) is too big, you will also take into account values of the function in the "wrong" side (positive or negative) of the graph, where $f$ has a different behavior and therefore won't describe "what the function is doing" around the point $a$

The above holds for every function that has a discontinuity in its domain.